# VBA: Limiting cell range with functions

Tags: vba, excel

How do you write a function in VBA that lets the user enter a range as a parameter, and set the upper/lower bounds for that range (in case they enter a whole column)?

I have a function that looks at a cell and sees if it contains any words listed in a glossary (I just allow the user to select a column (range) that is the list of glossary terms. I currently use a for each cell in range loop to go through the range, but I don't want to waste steps going through ALL the cells in column A, even if I am checking first if Len(cell.value) <> 0.

I am guessing it's done with a select statement, but I'm now sure how to do that to a range that was passed as a parameter (I call it cell_range right now).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Added Info:
The data type of the range is of type string. It's a list of English words (glossary terms) and I am writing a function that will look at a cell and see if it includes any of the terms from the glossary. If it does, the code returns the glossary term plus the offset cell to the right (the translated term).

EDIT (06.20.11)
Finalized code thanks to experimentation and suggestions below. It takes a cell and looks for any glossary terms in it. It returns the list of terms, plus the translated terms (second column in glossary).

```
Function FindTerm(ByVal text As String, ByVal term_list As range) As String

Static glossary As Variant
Dim result As String
Dim i As Long

glossary = range(term_list.Cells(1, 1), term_list.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown))

For i = 1 To UBound(glossary)
    If InStr(text, glossary(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
       result = (glossary(i, 1) & " = ") & (glossary(i, 2) & vbLf) & result
    End If
Next

If result <> vbNullString Then
    result = Left$(result, (Len(result) - 1))
End If

FindTerm = result
```

End Function

Comment: What data type is `cell_range`? Is it a `Range` or a `String`? Please show us (relevant parts of) your code.

Comment: Please note that I use the last left$() if the list isn't blank otherwise it would have a line break at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question, you can't restrict what is passed as a parameter, but you can derive a new range from a passed range.

That said, looping through a range is *very* slow.  There are may alternative methods:

- Query based methods, as suggested by Remou
- Copy the range to a variant array and loop through that
  `Dim vDat as variant`
  `vDat = cell_range`
  vDat is now a two dimensional array
- Use the built in search function Find
  `cell_range.Find  ...`
- Use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` (and/or `.Index` `.VLookup`)

Which one best suits depend on the specifics of your case

**Edit**

Demo of the variant array approach

```
Function Demo(Glossary As Range, search_cell As Range) As String
    Dim aGlossary As Variant
    Dim aSearch() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim FoundList As New Collection
    Dim result As String
    Dim r As Range
    ' put data into array
    aGlossary = Range(Glossary.Cells(1, 1), Glossary.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))

    ' assuming words in search cell are space delimited
    aSearch = Split(search_cell.Value, " ")
    'search for each word from search_cell in Glossary
    For i = LBound(aSearch) To UBound(aSearch)
        For j = LBound(aGlossary, 1) To UBound(aGlossary, 1)
            If aSearch(i) = aGlossary(j, 1) Then
                ' Add to found list
                FoundList.Add aSearch(i), aSearch(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'return list as comma seperated list
    result = ""
    For i = 1 To FoundList.Count
        result = result & "," & FoundList.Item(i)
    Next
    Demo = Mid(result, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: I've never tried working with variant arrays, so I'll give that a shot! How would use instr(text, cell.value) with a variant array though? (sorry for the additional question).

Comment: Thank you for the demo, this is extreamlly helpful! I think I should be okay from here on! Thanks!!!

Comment: I decided to go with your sugestion and it worked just perfect for what I wanted. i updated it in the question! Thanks!

Comment: @Issum great, glad to help.  BTW if you find an answer useful you should accept it (click the tick)

Comment: Just did! I'm still pretty new at stackoverflow so thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not limit your loop to the filled cells efficiently?

```
For Each c In Range("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   ....
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is using the specialcells faster than checking if the length is not 0?

Comment: MUCH faster. Generally built-in stuff IS much faster than what you program through VBA

Comment: I tried it out and it seems on my machine at least that using For Each cell in Range and then check "if len(cell.value) <> 0 then... was much faster than looping through the loop using the code above. I was testing on 2003 though, and normally I use Excel 2007 so maybe there is a difference. I'm happy to learn about specialcells though, so thanks for your comment either way!

Comment: @Issun : Thanks for your feedback. I am very surprised about the speed difference that way ! Isn't there any other factor that makes the difference ? Like an unnecessary Select in one version ?

Comment: Ultimately the fastest method was to use the variant array that was suggested below. No idea why this and my original method are slower... I tried on excel 2007 on a faster machine and no luck. When you see my code above, maybe it's a case that I wasn't clear in what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident there are no gaps:

```
''Last cell in column A, or first gap
oSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select

''Or last used cell in sheet - this is not very reliable, but 
''may suit if the sheet is not much edited
Set r1 = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

Otherwise, you may need http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142526 to determine the last cell.

**EDIT Some notes on selecting the column**

```
Dim r As Range
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Set r = Application.Selection
Set r1 = r.Cells(1, 1)
r1.Select
Set r2 = r1.End(xlDown)

If r2.Row > Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row Then
    MsgBox "Problem"
Else
    Debug.Print r1.Address
    Debug.Print r2.Address
End If

Set r = Range(r1, r2)
Debug.Print r.Address
```

However, you can also use ADO with Excel, but whether it will work for you depends on what you want to do:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Dim a As String

''It does not matter if the user has selected a whole column,
''only the data range will be picked up, nor does it matter if the
''user has selected several cells, except when it comes to the HDR
''I guess you could set HDR = Yes or No accordingly.

''One cell is slightly more difficult, but for one cell you would 
''not need anything like this palaver.

a = Replace(Application.Selection.Address, "$", "")

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used. 
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

''So this is not very interesting:
strSQL = "SELECT * " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$" & a & "]"

''But with a little work, you could end up with:

strSQL = "SELECT Gloss " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$A:A] " _
       & "WHERE Gloss Like '%" & WordToFind & "%'"

''It is case sensitive, so you might prefer:

strSQL = "SELECT Gloss " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$A:A] " _
       & "WHERE UCase(Gloss) Like '%" & UCase(WordToFind) & "%'"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results
''if you want to write out the recordset
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs=Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn=Nothing
```

Comment: THanks Remou. I was thinking of using that first idea, but I don't know what to do if the user selects column C for instance. I tried pluging in a variable where it says "A1" and it won't take, so no way that I know of to dynamically change what letter column it is... unless you know? THanks again!

Comment: @Issun I have added a few notes above that may help.